# IOS Push notification using Flash (AIR 2.5)

Tags: air

Has anybody used the IOS push notification using the lastest AIR 2.5 SDK for mobile? Could somebody please send me to any tutorial or example on implementing it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to send push notifications using the iPhone packager for Adobe Flash at this moment.
Although the Adobe team did some nice work with AIR 2.6; APNS implementation isn't one of them.

I hope they'll be able to implement APNS support in any future AIR update, that would be welcome feature especially with multiplayer gaming.